# How to query an SQLite3 database correlation matrix using a previously defined list

Tags: python, matrix, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database that looks like this:

```
|Tickers|A   |B   |C   |D   |E   |  
|-------|----|----|----|----|----|   
|A      |1.00|0.25|0.75|0.60|0.30|  
|B      |0.25|1.00|0.20|0.40|0.70|  
|C      |0.75|0.20|1.00|0.10|0.90|  
|D      |0.60|0.40|0.10|1.00|0.50|  
|E      |0.30|0.70|0.90|0.50|1.00|
```

I want to query this database to find the correlations of certain stocks (where the column meets the row for each stock) using a list in Python.  I've used the following code to create the list then query the database:

```
Stocks=['A','B','C']
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('CorrelationMatrix')
c = conn.cursor()
Correlations=[]
for i in range(0,len(Stocks)):
    c.execute("SELECT Stocks[i] FROM CorrelationMatrix WHERE Tickers=Stocks[i]")
for row in c.fetchall():
    Correlations.append(row)
print(Correlations)
```

I want the result of the query to create a list of the correlations for those 3 stocks (rather than all 5), like this:

> [1.00,0.75,0.25,0.25,1.00,0.20,0.75,0.20,1.00]

When I execute the code and print the Correlations list, it results in the following error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[i]": syntax error

It appears that I can't query the database with python lists?  Does anyone have a better solution for working with a matrix such as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string formatting to pass the variable to interpolate column names, try with:

```
Stocks=['A','B','C']
c.execute("""SELECT %s FROM CorrelationMatrix WHERE Tickers in %s"""%(','.join(Stocks),tuple(Stocks)))
rows = c.fetchall()
Correlations = [e for r in rows for e in r]
print(Correlations)
```

or

```
Stocks=['A','B','C']
c.execute("""SELECT {a},{b},{c} FROM CorrelationMatrix WHERE Tickers in (?,?,?)""".format(a=Stocks[0], b=Stocks[1], c=Stocks[2]),(Stocks[0],Stocks[1],Stocks[2]))
rows = c.fetchall() #[(1.0, 0.25, 0.75), (0.75, 0.2, 1.0), (0.25, 1.0, 0.2)]
Correlations = [e for r in rows for e in r]
print(Correlations)
```

`Correlations` will be:

```
[1.0, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.2, 1.0, 0.25, 1.0, 0.2]
```